# Refresh a listview outside of a widget in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a Flutter application which comprises of a scaffold with a slider and a tabview.

The tabview comprises of a List which is show on each tab as seen in the picture below.

```
  List<Widget> widgetList = <Widget>[
    Post(),
    Feed(),
    Location(),
    HomePage(),
    Feed(),
  ];
```

Now I would like to refresh the current tab on screen when the slider is moved. However, since the classes are private i.e. `_HomePageState`, I do not know how to access the `refreshList()` method as shown in the snippet below.

**homepage.dart:**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var list;
  var random;

  var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    random = Random();
    refreshList();
  }

  Future<Null> refreshList() async {
    refreshKey.currentState?.show(atTop: false);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

    setState(() {
      list = List.generate(random.nextInt(10), (i) => "Item $i");
    });

    return null;
  }
}
```

The slider is not baked into each listview Widget i.e. `homepage.dart` as the slider values is applicable to each individual tab. How can I refresh the inner listview widget when the outer widget with the slider is moved?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways to deal with this:

1. You could pass down the `PageController` and the page index to your page widgets. In your page widgets can then listen to the changes (`pageController.addListener(...)`) and compare the currently centered page with their page index.
2. Create one `ChangeNotifier` for every page that you want to refresh:

   ```
   final postRefresh = ChangeNotifier();
   final feedRefresh = ChangeNotifier();
   ...

   // build method of parent:
   List<Widget> widgetList = <Widget>[
     Post(refresh: postRefresh),
     Feed(refresh: feedRefresh),
     ...
   ];

   // initState method of parent:
   pageController.addListener(() {
     final roundedPage = pageController.page.round();
     if(roundedPage == 0) {
       postRefresh.notifyListeners();
     }
     else if(roundedPage == 1) {
       feedRefresh.notifyListeners();
     }
     // ...
   })
   ```
3. You could also give your page widgets a global key (for that, their `State` classes must be public):

   ```
   // class body of parent:
   final postPageKey = GlobalKey<PostPageState>();
   final feedPageKey = GlobalKey<FeedPageState>();

   // build method of parent:
   List<Widget> widgetList = <Widget>[
     Post(key: postPageKey),
     Feed(key: feedPageKey),
     ...
   ];

   // initState method of parent:
   pageController.addListener(() {
     final roundedPage = pageController.page.round();
     if(roundedPage == 0) {
       postPageKey.currentState?.refresh();
     }
     else if(roundedPage == 1) {
      feedPageKey.currentState?.refresh();
     }
     // ...
   })
   ```